# How to use boolean logic in new column assignment?

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I have a dataframe with two boolean columns.

I am trying to assign a new column using the following logic:

```
df['C'] = df['A']==True and df['B']==False
```

The error says the truth of a Series is ambiguous. I can see the problem but I don't know how to tell it that I want it perform the operation row-wise.

Comment: df['C'] = (df['A']==True) & (df['B']==False)

Comment: provide some data and example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: `df['C'] = df.A & ~df.B`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df['C'] = (df['A']==True) & (df['B']==False)
```

Or better as pointed @Yakym Pirozhenko in comment is invert `B` column by `~`:

```
df['C'] = df['A'] & ~df['B']
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[True, False, True, True],
                   'B':[True, False, False, True]})

print (df)
       A      B
0   True   True
1  False  False
2   True  False
3   True   True

df['C'] = df['A'] & ~df['B']
print (df)
       A      B      C
0   True   True  False
1  False  False  False
2   True  False   True
3   True   True  False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['C']=((df['A']==True) & (df['B']==False))*1
```